# Swift PrepareForSegue NSIndexPath error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, swift2

I want to prepare my segue via:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue?.identifier != "fromOpenChatsToLogIn" {
        if let controller: ChatViewController? = segue?.destinationViewController as? ChatViewController {
            if let cell: onlineUserCell? = sender as? onlineUserCell {
                let user = OneRoster.userFromRosterAtIndexPath(indexPath: tableView.indexPathForCell(cell!)!)
                controller!.recipient = user
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `onlineUserCell` is my custom cell. Also, that's my userFromRosterAtIndexPath:

```
class func userFromRosterAtIndexPath(indexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject {
    return sharedInstance.fetchedResultsController()!.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject
}
```

so, when I select my cell it crashes with:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

on line:

```
let user = OneRoster.userFromRosterAtIndexPath(indexPath: tableView.indexPathForCell(cell!)!)
```

What is wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Swift introduced type inference, and the best practices is to use it properly, so write your code like this

```
if let controller = segue?.destinationViewController as? ChatViewController {
   if let cell = sender as? onlineUserCell {
   }
}
```

Also you should set an exception breakpoint in Xcode ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode)), to see more clearly where you're crashing.

In your case it was in

`override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)`

You should use the following statement :

```
if segue.identifier == "fromOpenChatsToLogIn" {
} else {
}
```

Your Login ViewController doesn't require an user, therefore it crashed at

```
let user = OneRoster.userFromRosterAtIndexPath(indexPath: tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!)
```

Because there is no `cell`, and the `sender` in `prepareForSegue` is definitely NOT a cell.

For you second issue, the fix was easy.

You are sending `OneRoster.userFromRosterAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath)` in

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("fromUsersListToChatView", sender: OneRoster.userFromRosterAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath))
```

So you don't need a cell or anything since you already have the `user` object !

Set the `recipient` like this :

```
controller?.recipient = sender as? XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject
```

Just replace your `prepareForSegue` method to the following and it will work:

```
if segue.identifier == "fromOpenChatsToLogIn" {
} else {
    let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? ChatViewController         
    controller?.recipient = sender as? XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check, wether your `cell` is `nil` or your `userFromRosterAtIndexPath` return `nil`

Comment: `po cell` returns `nil`

Comment: Did you check what `sender` is ? I guess it's not a cell so it doesn't pass your `as?`

Comment: how can I check `sender`? with `po sender` it returns `nil`. In other my project I did not use `sender`, but here I took it from GitHub repo and tried to change it with my custom cell, so it now crashes

Comment: Well, if sender send nil, it's normal you get nil in the end then.

Comment: So, how can I fix it? Can you help me, please

Comment: Why don't you use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90196/discussion-between-orkhan-alizade-and-anc-ainu).

Answer (score 0):

My advise would to set tag on each cell and then in your `prepareForSegue` method, get the cell, get the tag and then tweak the code for `userFromRosterAtIndexPath` to take that tag instead. That tag value could be row number of the cell. See if this makes sense in your context.

Comment: it returns `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSIndexPath'` error

Comment: My bad - here `indexPath` would always have some value. Could you please try once with tag approach I have suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Check casting like this.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "PhotoScrollerViewController" {
        if let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? PhotoScrollerViewController {
            var cell:UICollectionViewCell = (sender as? UICollectionViewCell)!

           //Code here
        }
    }
}
```